# lambda function complaining about file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I trying to move a python script into lambda, so I can automate the process.  But I am having problems.

The script is from  [SecurityHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-securityhub-multiaccount-scripts) and I am trying enter the handler name, which I have detailed as follows: `enablesecurityhub.assume_role`, for the script - `enablesecurityhub.py`.  But I am getting the following error message:

> Unable to import module 'enablesecurityhub': No module named enablesecurityhub.

I have performed a zip, which includes all the imports {pip install -r requirements.txt -t ./} and I have uploaded to S3 - it is approx 10mb in size the file up.

```
cat requirements.txt 
boto3
argparse
utils
OrderedDict
input
```

But I am not sure what I am doing wrong for the handler.  Please can you advise?

Comment: Is `enablesecurityhub.py` at the root of the .zip file, or in a subfolder?

Comment: root of the zip file.

Comment: securityhub_v2/enablesecurityhub.py and the folder is zipped as follows -  securityhub_v2.zip

Comment: Don't zip the folder.  Zip the *contents* of the folder.